# Akamai to Self Hosting Option In Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, web, tags, analytics, adobe-analytics

My customer is moving from Adobe DTM(akamai) to Self hosting option.

I don't know the procedure how to do it?

Or

Is this right way to move as per my understanding, self hosting requires lot of manual work.

Please correct me if i am wrong or let me know the correct process.

Thanks,
Payal

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily require a lot of extra work, especially if you set up the FTP option. http://www.digitaldatatactics.com/examples/selfHost.html walks through how I got self-hosting working (going the non-FTP route, though FTP could be similar). 
Mind you, some of this may change with Launch, but... this gives the rough idea.

Comment: Hi jenn thankyou.

Can you please tell me what would be my role because i am working on analytics dtm so what changes i have to do.please jen and this process is really very feasible or not.